# Use google plus API to check availablity of personalized url

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth

How can I use the google plus api to check if a personalized url is taken? Do I need to use OAuth to check this?

I've successfully connected to the G+ api using OAuth but can't find this simple functionality anywhere after checking the documentation.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share you research before asking for help. State the background of the question, what you have tried, or what you have read before asking this question. I'm sure good answers will come to good questions!

Comment: Without improving your question, I'm sure you will get answers like this: https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Answer (score 0):

Google+ does not provide an API for specifically checking the availability of a custom URL; however, you could use the [`People.get`](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) endpoint to specifically query for to check for results for a specific ID, such as "+LarryPage" (response fields limited to id,name):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/%2BLarryPage?fields=id%2Cname&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "id": "106189723444098348646",
  "name": {
    "familyName": "Page",
    "givenName": "Larry"
  }
}
```

Or if you try an invalid custom ID, like "+SergeyBatmanBrin", you'd get an `HTTP 404` as the response because that ID doesn't exist.

You will need to register a project in the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) to register your client and get an API key or OAuth client ID to allow your app to perform these queries.